# Cannot convert unconverted lead

Tags: account, leads, convert

When trying to convert a lead which hasn't been converted I get one of the two following errors:

> Error: System.DmlException: Update failed. First exception on row 0 with id 00QN0000005zrQtMAI; first error: CANNOT_UPDATE_CONVERTED_LEAD, cannot reference converted lead: [] (System Code)

Or

> Error: System.DmlException: Update failed. First exception on row 0 with id 00QN0000005zrQtMAI; first error: CANNOT_UPDATE_CONVERTED_LEAD, cannot reference converted lead: [] Class.leadconvert.BulkLeadConvert.updateLead: line 1440, column 1 Class.leadconvert.BulkLeadConvert.convertLead: line 157, column 1

In both instances the object Id given is the Id of the lead I am trying to convert.  When I go back and check its status it is still `IsConverted = False`, with no convert timestamps.

There are two workflows on the lead object, both of which only send emails. There are two triggers which act on leads but both are part of managed packages.

This only happens when trying to create a new account when converting the lead. If I convert using an already existing account, I haven't run into any issues.

This link is the only one I could find which references the bottom error:
https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000enoqQAA. 
The mentioned package is not in use in this org.

Comment: I think, from the managed package it is updating converted lead, the SOQL should check IsConverted = False, before performing DML operation